# What is wrong with this sequelize query

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm biuld an Webapp with Sequelize ORM. My query:

```
if(req.query.dataTransIni && req.query.dataTransFim ){
      condition.data = {
        [op.or] : {
            [op.between] : [
              {logdatatransacao : moment(req.query.dataTransIni).format("YYYY-MM-DD")},
              {logdatatransacao : moment(req.query.dataTransFim).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
            ],
            [op.between] : [
              {arqdataTransacao : moment(req.query.dataTransIni).format("YYYY-MM-DD")},
              {arqdataTransacao : moment(req.query.dataTransFim).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
            ]            
        }
      }
    }
```

The error in console

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value { arqdataTransacao: '2019-10-10' }
```

What I want looks like it

```
select * from myTable 
where 
logdatatransacao between ('2020-02-27') and ('2020-02-28')
or
arqdataTransacao between ('2020-02-27') and ('2020-02-28')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are specifying the column names within an object again in the `between` Op.

The following works for me by supplying an scalar array:

```
    const startDate = moment('2020-01-01').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    const endDate = moment('2020-01-02').format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    const departments = await sequelize.models.department.findAll({
        where: {
            created: {
                [Sequelize.Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
            }
        },
        attributes: ['name'],
        raw: true,
        nest: true
    });
```

SQL:

```
SELECT "name" FROM "departments" AS "department" WHERE "department"."created" BETWEEN '2020-01-01 08:00:00.000 +00:00' AND '2020-01-02 08:00:00.000 +00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks for try help me Samuel G, I'll try your solution here

Comment: Yeap. Thanks so much. I'll post my solution

Comment: With your answer I got fix my sintaxe problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem doing this:

```
var condition = [];
...
if(req.query.dataTransIni && req.query.dataTransFim ){
      condition.push({
        [op.or] : [{
            logdatatransacao : {
              [op.between] : [
                moment(new Date(req.query.dataTransIni)).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                moment(new Date(req.query.dataTransFim)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            arqdataTransacao : {
              [op.between] : [
                moment(new Date(req.query.dataTransIni)).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                moment(new Date(req.query.dataTransFim)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
              ]
            }
        }]
      })
    }
...
const Vscmc = await Modelvscmc.findAll({ 
      offset : ((offsetPage-1)*limit),
      limit: limit,
      where : condition
    })
```

My problem was Brackets and Parentheses objects.